# Telegram Bot make InlineKeyboardMarkup buttons unclickable

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

Is there any way to make InlikeKeyBoardMarkup buttons unclickable after user click on any button in? I've searched in google and as far as I understand I can only disappear ReplyKeyboardMarkup buttons, what does not satisfies me.

I am using Telegram-Bot library in C#

Comment: you mean visual unclickability?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done visually but there is an alternative I've been using for a while:

Use **editMessageReplyMarkup** method and generate same keyboard layout but the button you want to become unclickable set as `callback_data` type with value like `null` or any other value you won't be using, clicking it will send **Callback Query** to the bot which you can simply not answer to or **answerCallbackQuery** it instantly (the 'clock' icon on the button will instantly disappear).

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the message of the question or edit it to say something like:

"I asked you if you like me and your replied of course."